# ejecting new divs with .before across large website, hide on index page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

**Problem:**

```
$( "#google_map_vc_box" ).before( $( "#banners" ) );
$( "#google_map_vc_box" ).after( $( ".css3button" ) );
```

With the above method I'm inserting new `divs` before and after element across a large sized website; I am implementing this on the `index.php` or homepage

Problem; on the homepages my new divs are showing up and they shouldn't be, I ***ONLY*** want these new divs to show when they are populating before and after element `#google_map_vc_box`

Inline markup for new divs is on the home or index.php page (Joomla Site)

```
<button type="button" name="" value="" class="css3button">“Buy this item directly from 'Fusion Cine'”</button>

<div id="banners" style="padding: 10px;">
<center>
<div id="slider">
<a href="#">
<img src="http://i5.photobucket.com/albums/y191/venus1982/banner_468x60.gif"><br>
</a>
<a href="#">
<img src="http://www.kelownadragonboatclub.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Adspace-banner-468x60.png"><br>
</a>
<a href="#">
<img src="http://divathemes.com/demo_classy/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/468x60placeholder.png"><br>
</a>
<a href="#">
<img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_aAjcAMHOGT4/TLqvrBFKCpI/AAAAAAAAFNM/yL_OFQh9M1Q/s1600/banner_468.png"><br>
</a>
<a href="#">
<img src="http://themecanon.com/themes/nosh/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/banner_468x60.jpg"><br>
</a>
<a href="#">
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/fullban"><br>
</a>
<a href="#">
<img src="http://www.zero-art.ru/images/placeholder_banner468x60.gif"><br>
</a>
<a href="#">
<img src="http://mycashbox.net/static/media/images/placeholder/468x60.gif"><br>
</a>
<a href="#">
<img src="http://i5.photobucket.com/albums/y191/venus1982/banner_468x60.gif"><br>
</a>
<a href="#">
<img src="http://i5.photobucket.com/albums/y191/venus1982/banner_468x60.gif"><br>
</a>
<a href="#">
<img src="http://i5.photobucket.com/albums/y191/venus1982/banner_468x60.gif"><br>
</a>
</div>
</center>
</div>
```

I have tried toggling, `display:hidden display:none` and even     `$( "#google_map_vc_box" ).after( $( ".css3button" ) ).css( 'display', 'block' );`

With no success, any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you likely need to do is an if statement.

For example:

```
if ($('#home-page').length) {
    $( "#google_map_vc_box" ).before( $( "#banners" ) );
    $( "#google_map_vc_box" ).after( $( ".css3button" ) );
}
```

I am just using `#home-page` as an example. So is there a unique id that only appears on the home page and not on any others? If so, use that. If you don't have one, I'd recommend just adding a unique id to the home page body tag.

For example if your home page has this html for the body tag

```
<body id="home-page">
```

Then the `if ($('#home-page').length)` will check if the length is either true or false. If the id #home-page does not appear on the page, then the inserts will not happen, but if you do have that element on the page it will.

Comment: So I just did that via the body tag and implemented like so at: jQuery(document).ready(function(){
if ($('#home-page').length) {
    $( "#google_map_vc_box" ).before( $( "#banners" ) );
    $( "#google_map_vc_box" ).after( $( ".css3button" ) );
  }
});

Comment: I think I need this reversed anyway

Comment: This solution also cannot work because it's a dynamic website so it appears appending ID to body tag would populate across.